# How do I creat a navbar that when clicked it opens on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a little difficult creating a navbar that when clicked it opens a small window on the same page like on [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSR4t.jpg).

Comment: Are you referring to the Service section in the image? If yes, it looks more like a popup; you can create a popup/dialog and make it slide.

Comment: It could be easier to help you if you add what you tried to do so far.

Answer (score 1):

Create the small window as it's own div:

```
<div id="myID"> This content will show when I click the navbar</div>
```

Add the following CSS:

```
#myID{

display: none; 

}
```

Then use some script to show/hide the element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// change #nav to whatever the ID of the nav element is.
  $('#nav').on('click', function(){

    // show/hide pop up on click
    $('#myID').toggle();

  });
});
```

Comment: It uses jQuery, isn't it?

Comment: Yes this is jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Navbar like this. This is the only dummy. In given image, they have one fix element and when you click on nav element according to that they are updating the content of that element.

```js
    $('#myNav').find('li a').click(function (e) {
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        $('#main').html($(this).html());
    });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #567;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myNav">
  <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Service</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="main">
  Home
</div>
```

It will help you to create a nav bar.